# mailto: does not properly set fields in a GroupWise 8 Message

Tags: javascript, html, struts, mailto, groupwise

I have been struggling all afternoon trying to get a simple `mailto:` tag to work. I've scoured the internet, but so far none of the suggested fixes have solved the problem.

**The Problem**

I have a webpage that I want users to be able to send an email from. This page will be used on an internal network, and requires that a recipient, subject, and body is dynamically added to the message when the button is clicked.

To solve the problem, I am trying to use the mailto tag, and Groupwise 8 launches a new message correctly when I only have a recipient listed. However, when trying to set anything other than the To: field, the data is simply appended to the To: field.

For example, in my jsp page I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendMail() {
        alert('Trying to send mail!');
        var link = "mailto:myaddress@mydomain.org"
             + "?subject=Testing the automated email template"
             + "&body=Testing testing testing" 
        ;
        window.location.href = link;
    }
</script>

...

<input type="button" onclick="sendMail();" value="Send email" />
```

So when I click the button, I would expect an email to myaddress@mydomain.org, with a subject of "Testing the automated email template", and a body of "Testing testing testing". Instead, however, the entire link string is simply put into the To: field of the email message.

I have tried a number of variations of mailto, embedding the mailto into an `<a>` tag instead of Javascript, and escaping the string. Nothing changes the outcome when Groupwise creates the new message.

Any advice on how to fix this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's not much standardization around the "mailto:" behavior. Beyond just the "To:" address, nothing is certain to work.

Comment: Have you tried *encoding* the string (e.g. space = %20)?

Comment: @SirCrispalot I have tried using both escape() and encodeURIComponent(). No luck with either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to solve this problem was to scrap using mailTo. I wound up having to create a new sendEmail action and bean in order to handle the creation of the email that in the logic part of the application.

Hopefully this stops someone else from wasting their time trying to find a way to make GroupWise behave with `<mailto:>`!